# Easy way to cite academic references in the README.md of a github-repo

Tags: github, markdown, readme

I was just wondering if there is any easy way that I can use a `.bib`-file to create academic references in the README of a github site.
In `rmarkdown` I'm used to just do the following in the text:

`@test2010`

and if I have specified the correct bibtex-file in the yaml-header it works perfectly.

Is there anything similar in "normal" github markdown?

Answer (score 1):

Bibliographies are not supported in [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://github.github.com/gfm/)(GFM). The workaround is producing GFM from R Markdown.

Step: create `README.Rmd` and `bibliography.bib` and knit `README.Rmd`.

`README.Rmd`:

```yaml
---
output:
  md_document:
    variant: markdown_github
bibliography: bibliography.bib
---

[@xie2018]
```

`bibliography.bib`:

```
@Book{xie2018,
  title = {R Markdown: The Definitive Guide},
  author = {Yihui Xie and J.J. Allaire and Garrett Grolemund},
  publisher = {Chapman and Hall/CRC},
  address = {Boca Raton, Florida},
  year = {2018},
  note = {ISBN 9781138359338},
  url = {https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown},
}
```

The output `README.md`:

```markdown
(Xie, Allaire, and Grolemund 2018)

<div id="refs" class="references csl-bib-body hanging-indent">

<div id="ref-xie2018" class="csl-entry">

Xie, Yihui, J. J. Allaire, and Garrett Grolemund. 2018. *R Markdown: The
Definitive Guide*. Boca Raton, Florida: Chapman; Hall/CRC.
<https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown>.

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: how would that work for creating and editing a `readme.md` on github? Can this be automated?

Comment: You need to create `.Rmd` file and compile it into `.md` file. See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/ . Maybe you can automate compiling via GitHub Actions.